# How to loop through numbers, when one of the fields numbers are constructed differently?

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach, counter, custom-fields

I have a bunch of custom fields on one of my post types, that is displayed randomly but in a fixed order. The names of the custom fields are always the same, and for every loop there is an increasing counter added to the custom field names.

Like this:

```
custom_text
custom_text1
custom_text2

custom_image
custom_image1
custom_image2

custom_video
custom_video1
custom_video2
```

The problem is, there is one field that begins with the number one, like this:

```
custom_special1
custom_special2
custom_special3
```

Right now, it's impossible to change this behaviour. Problem is, this makes the custom_special fields show up in the wrong place of the output, the first one shows up together with the fields with the number 1 at then end, instead of with the empty ones.

I need to tweak the code below with some kind of if statement, that says something like:

*if $custom_special . $counter {output the result one step down}*

The important thing is that it has to show up in between the other fields, so I can't have a separate function for the special field.

Here's my code, I hope some of you gurus out there can help me with a solution!

```
// max custom field index
    $number = 40;
    // the counter
    $counter = '';
    // the meta keys to check for
    $keys = array(
        'custom_text',
        'custom_image',
        'custom_video'
    );
    // all our custom field values
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );

// loop over our counter
while( $counter < $number ){
    // loop over each of the keys
    foreach( $keys as $key ){
        // check if a custom field with key + counter exists
        if( isset( $custom_fields[ $key . $counter ] ) ){
            // output the field
            // values will be in an array, 0 is the first index.
            // you can loop over these as well if you have multiple values.
            if (strpos($key, 'custom_text') !== false) {
                $first = '<h2>';
                $second = '</h2>';
                echo $first . $custom_fields[ $key . $counter ][0] . $second;
            }
            if (strpos($key, 'custom_image') !== false) {
                $first = '<img src="';
                $second = '">';
                echo $first . $custom_fields[ $key . $counter ][0] . $second;
            }   
            if (strpos($key, 'custom_video') !== false) {
                $first = '<p>';
                $second = '</p>';
                echo $first . $custom_fields[ $key . $counter ][0] . $second;
            }   
        }
    }
    // increment the counter
    $counter++;
}
```

I have thought about some different solutions, but still haven't been able to find one. My first idea is some kind of if statement, and the other one is to strip the numbers from the special field before the loop, and then rebuild it the way the other ones are constructed.

Still haven't been able to successfully create this though.

I hope that someone out there have a suggestion! Thanks a lot!

// Jens.

Comment: `$counter++;` should be **inside** your `foreach` loop, not outside

Comment: `else if( isset( $custom_fields[ 'custom_special' . (1 + $counter) ] ) ){ // ...` ?

Comment: @RC. This doesn't seem to work, since the custom_special field needs to be fetched in between the other fields. Problem is, the fields that are fetched are based on the $counter, so the custom_special are recognized one step to late. Understand?

I think I need some kind of function before the loop, that says something like: if custom_special1, remove 1. If custom_special2 or more, subtract by 1. Any ideas on this perhaps?

Comment: I don't see why not, if the proposed `else if` is placed on the outermost `if`, maybe you should provide a complete minimal sample reproducing your issue

Answer (score 0):

when you want to acecess this

```
custom_special1
custom_special2
custom_special3
```

using same counter you have for others you can simple do :

```
$counter2 = $counter+1;
$custom_fields[ $key . $counter2 ]
```

so for custom_special1 , you use $counter2 witch is $counter added 1 value.

Just a quick fix code ideea